# How to select columns that contains partially a string in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

I need to search for rows in a table and I need to select the values that starts partially with a provided value.
I known how search for a pattern but I have the pattern in the table, not in the value, and I don't know if its' possible.
My question is partically like a LIKE, but backward :)

Example:

If in my table I have the values 234, 1567, 31, 3145 and the provided value is
23434 I need to select 234, if the provided value is 95214 I need to return a empty select and, finally if the provided value is 314, I need to return 3145.
If this possible? How? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `like "%somestring%"`?

Comment: Normal query, if I find value A into the column B is SELECT * FROM T WHERE B LIKE "A%" but I have tried SELECT * FROM T WHERE "A" LIKE B+"%" due to I find the values in B into the string A but don't works. Note that the provided value is more large that the stored value, that is a prefix of the provided value.

Comment: Why have you got a row that is containing the value and your search-pattern? Can you please describe your table to us.

Comment: Ok, In my app I filter incoming calls. The user provides various phone numbers and I need to filter depending on the numbers. For now, I filter exact numbers, but I'm like to filter by start number. By example, in my database I store the "+34" is due the user needs to filter all incoming calls from Spain. When I receive a call from number +34343432 I need to check if a number in the database is a prefix for the received incoming call, in order to filter it. For now, I get a cursor to all records in the database and I check the values in Java, but this is slow andl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you check a column's value against a pattern:

```
SELECT ... WHERE MyTable.Name LIKE 'prefix%'
```

However, both operands of LIKE are string expressions.
You can simply put the column on the right side:

```
SELECT ... WHERE '23434' LIKE MyTable.Pattern
```

If the column value does not include the '%', you have to add it:

```
SELECT ... WHERE '23434' LIKE MyTable.Prefix || '%'
```

To get the longest match, you have to get the one that compares larger than all others, i.e., add:

```
... ORDER BY MyTable.Prefix DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is working: SELECT ... WHERE '23434' LIKE MyTable.Prefix || '%'     Thanks!